# Calculate area of Rectilinear Polygon in C

Tags: c, math, geometry, area

I have to develop a C program for a given set of input values, where we describe the rectanged figure by its boundary by specifying a starting point and a series of movements in four basic directions – as if we were going around the formation along its boundary.
We enter each movement in the direction (WESN) and length – "W 3" means moving from the current position three steps west (left).

[image]

The figure in Figure 1 could be described — starting from the upper-right corner — as:

> "W 6, S 2, W 3, S 2, E 1, S 2, E 2, N 1, E 2, N 1, E 2, N 1, W 2, N 1,
> E 3, S 3, E 1, N 5".

My problem is:

1. What is such a shape called in geometry?
2. How can I calculate the area of such a shape? I have lengths of all the sides as W6, S4 etc.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems more like a [math.se] problem. Once you learn how to do it in geometry, it should become obvious how to translate that to C.

Comment: It's called a polygon.

Comment: More specifically it is a concave polygon

Comment: You can scan square by square vertically (or horizontally). Once you cross a boundary once, you know, that you are "inside" the polygon. Once you cross it again - you are outside. And so on. So count the squares that are "inside".

Comment: @Barmar I don't think a geometrical solution can provide a generic programming solution here. Geometrically you would just break it into rectangles intuitively and add up their areas.

Comment: Use [A  = ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area)  Works for any polygon - effectively breaking it down into triangles.

Comment: Yes, is there any algorithm to check for touching , crossing or intersecting lines of such a polygon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape is called [polyomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino). It's special case of polygon.

The problem of finding the area can be solved by starting at point `(0,0)` with a polygon of area `0`. Next, extending the area by rectangle while moving horizontally.

Assume that the current point is `(x,y)`. Moving to east by `d` unit means adding a rectangle at points `(x,0) -> (x,y) -> (x + d, y) -> (x + d, 0)`. Rectangle's area is `d * y`.
When moving west one needs to subtract the rectangle.

[image]

The final area is positive if the walk is clockwise or negative if the path was counter-clockwise.

This approach results in a very simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0, y = 0, A = 0, d;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { 
        if        (c == 'W' && scanf(" %d", &d) == 1) {
            x += d;
            A += d * y;
        } else if (c == 'E' && scanf(" %d", &d) == 1) {
            x -= d;
            A -= d * y;
        } else if (c == 'N' && scanf(" %d", &d) == 1) {
            y += d;
        } else if (c == 'S' && scanf(" %d", &d) == 1) {
            y -= d;
        }
    }
    if (A < 0) A = -A;
    printf("%d\n", A);
    return 0;
}
```

For input from the question is gives the expected answer of `33`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would it be possible to check if the lines in the walk at some point intersect, touch or cross one another. Thanks

Comment: @AhsanAli, it is far more complicated if O(n) or O(n log n) algorithm is desired. I'll try to figure something out

Answer (score 4):

This can be called a rectilinear polygon.

A general algorithm for calculating the area of any polygon is:

- Let (xo, yo) be the starting point (“o” for old).
- Initialize a sum S to zero.
- For each movement:

  - Calculate the new point (xn, yn) (“n” for new) from the movement and the old point.
  - Add xn•yo−xo•yn to S.
  - Set xo=xn and yo=yn.
- The area inside the polygon is |S|/2.

The above presumes the last movement closes the polygon, so the last point is the starting point. If it does not, a copy of the starting point should be saved and used to finish the sum with the last point.

This uses the [sum/algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area) [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) pointed out.